# vb.net application showing like an xp app

Tags: vb.net

I was working on a project and out of a sudden it runs weird: FI the progress bar changed from looking like this:

[image: old format]

to this:

[image: new format]

Not only the progress bar changed but the whole app did. Buttons, trackbars, you name it. It basically looks like its an xp program and I have no idea why.

one of the things I tried to do to fix this was to create a new project,and copy my forms into the new project. it worked perfectly as long as I chose my.application.(project name) as the startup object however if i chose a form or restart the solution. it will show the XP theme again

Comment: Has your Windows theme changed?

Comment: no nothing at all changed

Answer (score 1):

> it worked perfectly as long as I chose my.application.(project name) as the startup object however if i chose a form or restart the solution. it will show the XP theme again

The main application is calling [the `EnableVisualStyles()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles). The startup form is not. You can ensure this method is called yourself, *before any controls are created*.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so? maybe an article or a video?

Comment: *ps the hyperlink goes to a c# fix

Comment: @AhmedElbarbry It goes to microsoft .net documenation. Every page has C#, VB.Net, and F# versions at the same address, with a toggle option between which one you want. If you see C#, its because that's what you used the last time you access the docs site, and you can easily switch it to VB.

Comment: That is a very helpful information thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you create a C# WinForms Application project, the `Main` method looks like this:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

If you're not going to use the Application Framework in a VB project then you should write a similar `Main` method yourself, either in a module or your startup form:

```vb
<STAThread>
Shared Sub Main()
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
    Application.Run(New Form1)
End Sub
```

You would replace `Form1` with the name of your startup form.

It is the first line in that method that affects the theme of WinForms controls.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working. it shows me an error when I use "shared sub" however after some research I wrote:                  Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1
    <STAThread>
    Sub Main()
        Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Windows.Forms.Application.Run(New Form3)
    End Sub
End Module
but still wont work :(

Comment: *its not showing errors tho the code I provided

Comment: @AhmedElbarbry, you obviously can't declare a method `Shared` in a module. If you put it in your form, which is a class, then you declare it `Shared` and you can specify the form as the startup object. If you put it in a module then you don't declare it shared and you would select `Sub Main` as the startup object.